# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg' on Mac? (But winreg is a windows thing)

Tags: python-3.x, django, winreg

I am receiving the following error when I try to run a django shell. I am on a Mac though and everything that I can find says that this is associated with Windows and that winreg should be installed by default. Suggestions as to what I should be looking at?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/j/code/myproject/core/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/j/code/myproject/core/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 127, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read(), globals())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
```

Comment: What is the full command you are trying to run (`python manage.py blah`)?

Comment: @IainShelvington - `python manage.py shell < load_data.py`

Comment: The error is in `load_data.py`. Can you add the contents of `load_data.py` to your question?

Comment: @IainShelvington - I can't but I found the error based on your comment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Between when I had a working env and the env producing the error I made a lot of changes to a script that I was working on including installing packages and adding modules.

When I tried to run the script I received the error above.

In the comments, Iain asked for the command I was running and then the contents of the script. Out of all the things I was looking at -- I ignored this, because was certain it was something I installed, not the file I was working on.

At the top of the file, I found this line in the imports:

```
from winreg import FlushKey
```

^^ My best guess is that this was accidentally added while I was quickly moving across the keyboard too quickly and I didn't noticed and pressed some sort of key combo that added it.

This is a first.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. I'm not sure what prompted that autocomplete in the imports, but sure enough, there it was. Good eye!